# How do you make an infinite scroll page in Blogger?

Tags: blogger, infinite-scroll

I have a blog and would like to make it infinite scroll so you don't have to click through pages and pages of posts. Can anyone help me with the code, its in HTML according to **Blogger**?
Thanks :-)

Comment: Have you done any research? I'm sure there are tutorials out there...

Comment: You'd have to check whether Blogger has a theme with that functionality

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How to add infinite scrolling to Blogger blogs

Recently I read an interesting article, [How to add infinite scrolling to Blogger blogs](http://blog.manki.in/2012/04/how-to-add-infinite-scrolling-to.html). If you are using Blogger's blog, you can follow the instructions and give your blog, an infinite scroll without  much hassle.

The code for the widget is available on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/manki-scripts/source/browse/blogger-infinite-scrolling.js).  Feel free to copy or adapt the code.

From their [website](http://blog.manki.in/2012/04/how-to-add-infinite-scrolling-to.html), a few points worth mentioning:

> - This code uses [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/), so don’t forget to include it.
> - Custom template blogs may have to change the value of `postContainerSelector` variable in the code.
> - You have manually added [+1 buttons](http://www.google.com/+1/button/) to my blog.  Dynamically loaded posts won’t have the +1 buttons initialised; to fix that issue, I had to call `gapi.plusone.go()` every time new posts are added to the page.
> - `_WidgetManager` is a JavaScript object present in Blogger blogs.  You can query this object to find some page metadata. This code uses `_WidgetManager` to determine if the current page is showing a single post.  Infinite scrolling is not meaningful when only a single post needs to be displayed.

Answer (score 4):

HTML has no way of achieving this, you need JavaScript.

First set up an event listener for the scroll event. When it fires compare the distance scrolled to the height of the document and window.

If that indicates you are near the document, use XMLHttpRequest to download more content, and then the usual DOM suspects to add that content to the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this thru JQuery or JScript. HTML can not do this alone.

[Here](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/#.UHk_g2_ZHXB) is some example how you can get this.

Answer (score 2):

HTML doesn't specify absolutes in terms of height as it automatically allows for infinite scrolling (you can't say height="100%" for instance. In terms of CMS Blogs like blogger there should be user preferences available to say how many posts you want displayed, in the control panel. Alternatively if you are using a server side technology (e.g. php) with a database you can specify number of items displayed using record set paging.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener using JavaScript, means when a particular element comes to view port an event is fired and it fetches the data from some external resources. The data comes in JSON and you need to extract it and append the info in a DIV.
 For this I have made a script which fetches the data from Google Docs using Jquery and the event is fired after you scroll to the bottom most portion. [You can check the infinite scroll here](http://www.funbutlearn.com/2013/04/facebook-style-ajax-page-loading-for.html)